# Cakephp automatically filled form select for two word named belongTo model

Tags: forms, cakephp, model, naming-conventions

What is right naming or what am I missing to get automagic run for two word named Model. Actual model belong to the two words named model.

Exact example:
Tour belongs to Accommodation type. 
in database there is table `tours` and table `accommodation_types`
foreign key from tours is `tours.accommodation_type_id`
Snapshots of code below.

ToursController.php

```php
public function add() {
  //...
  $accommodation_types = $this->Tour->AccommodationType->find('list');
  //...
  $this->set(compact('accommodation_types', ...));
}
```

Tour.php

```php
//...
public $belongsTo = array(
  //...
  'AccommodationType' => array(
        'className' => 'AccommodationType',
        'foreignKey' => 'accommodation_type_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
  //...
);
```

Tours/add.ctp (inside a form)

```php
echo $this->Form->input('accommodation_type_id', array('label' => 'Accommodation type'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per convention the view vars names should be camelBacked. So rename the view var from `$accommodation_types` to `$accommodationTypes`. If you don't follow convention you have to explicitly specify the options var to use like this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('accommodation_type_id', array('options' => $accommodation_types, 'label' => 'Accommodation type'));
```

Comment: Thanks works well. I knew about options workaround but using automagic is deffinitely better.